# How to put Meta Tag in Print Window

Tags: tags, meta

We would like to print the content of a page using a print function.
Once the print function is clicked , it opens a popup by default and displays the content of the page there. I want to put a Cannonical Meta Tag there to indicate search engines that its a duplicate of the page it is printing. I do not know how to add meta tag in print window from javascript, pls can you help. The print function is below

`function printLyrics(){
       var prtContent = document.getElementById("view1");
       var URL = document.URL;
       console.log("URL " + URL);
       var WinPrint = window.open(URL, 'Song Lyrics', 'top=0, left=0');
       //$('head').append( '<meta name="description" content="this is new">' );
       WinPrint.document.write("<div style='text-align: center; font-family: Georgia, Times,            serif;font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;'>" + prtContent.innerHTML + "</div><div style='font-size: 10px; text-align: center; margin-top: 200px; font-family: courier;'>The above text is privded  by ss</div>");
       WinPrint.document.close();
       WinPrint.focus();
       WinPrint.print();
       WinPrint.close();
      }`